# How to remove part of a string before a ":" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a string `Abc: Lorem ipsum sit amet`, how can I use JavaScript/jQuery to remove the string before the `:` including the `:`. For example the above string will become: `Lorem ipsum sit amet`.

Comment: I added the javascript tag since it's in the question and more relevant to the question than jquery.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery here, regular JavaScript will do:

```
var str = "Abc: Lorem ipsum sit amet";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

Or, the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) version:

```
var str = "Abc: Lorem ipsum sit amet";
str = str.split(":").pop();
```

Or, the regex version (several variants of this):

```
var str = "Abc: Lorem ipsum sit amet";
str = /:(.+)/.exec(str)[1];
```

Comment: Note if there is more than one `:` in the string, the second variant will return the string following the *last* one rather than the first as in the others. It is unfortunate that there is no split-only-n-times option in JS's `split()` method, which would allow you to do a Python-style `.split(':', 1)[1]`. (There *is* an optional `number` argument, but it doesn't do what any reasonable person would expect.)

Comment: @bobince - You're right, I'm making a bit of an assumption here that he has a consistent `label: something` format, if that's not the case I'd go with the first option.

Comment: You can split and join to drop some elements based on separator.

`"Abc:Lorem_ipsum_sit_amet".split(':').slice(1).join('.');`

Comment: Hi, in jQuery I have this variable which I'd like to remove everything that comes after the character "|". I have been able to target the string by using this:
```var str = $('.order-product-list.align-left.box-content.any-1-1 > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > dl.align-left > dd:nth-child(8)');```

How do I do this? What comes after that character is dynamic and depends on the user on the web page. I want to hide/remove the last part after |

Comment: as mentioned in the comment by @AmriteshAnand if there are more than one : you will need to do this: (join should use the same delimiter used in split()
`var str = "Abc: Lorem ipsum :sit: amet";
str = str.split(":").slice(1).join(":")`

Answer (score 13):

As a follow up to [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092337/5517465) If your string contains multiple occurrences of `:` and you wish to only remove the substring before the first occurrence, then this is the method:

```js
var str = "Abc:Lorem:ipsum:sit:amet";
arr = str.split(":");
arr.shift();
str = arr.join(":");
// str = "Lorem:ipsum:sit:amet"
```