# javascript to bring back only a certain portion of text (codeigniter & JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have the below syntax:

```
$("#orderbynumber").autocomplete( 
 { 

 source: "get_orders_by_order_number", 
 messages: 
 { 
 noResults: '', 
 results: function() {} 
 }, 
 select: function( event, ui ) 
 { 
  var selectedObj = ui.item; 
  alert(selectedObj.value);
  //get prices
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
 $('input[name^="deliveryweek"]').val(result[0]);
 }); 

 } 
 });
```

the alert returns, `order number: Customer Name` for example `10827: Massmart`

what I want to do is strip away the `: Massmart` from `selectedObj.value`
so I want a new variable(for example) `selectedobjectorder = 10827`

I can then pass this as the order number to `get_sku_prices` function.

so something like:

```
$("#orderbynumber").autocomplete( 
 { 

 source: "get_orders_by_order_number", 
 messages: 
 { 
 noResults: '', 
 results: function() {} 
 }, 
 select: function( event, ui ) 
 { 
  var selectedObj = ui.item; 
  alert(selectedObj.value);
  //how to finx this code...
var selectedobjectorder= anything before :(selectedObj.value);
  alert(selectedobjectorder);

  //get prices
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:selectedobjectorder},function(result) { 
 $('input[name^="deliveryweek"]').val(result[0]);
 }); 

 } 
 });
```

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) is what you want.

```
var selectedobjectorder = parseInt(jQuery.trim(selectedObj.value));
```

Comment: Thanks elavarasan lee, works perfect. is there a way to say `all text before :`? in case of another example?

Comment: Will accept answer when allowed to (7 minutes) you were too fast :-)

Comment: lol... thank you :D
Regarding prepended-text, I'll check n will let you know.

Comment: And [**here it is**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092325/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-before-a-in-javascript). :)

Comment: Also U can use this: `replace('REGEX FOR STRING',your_variable_containin_text_n_number)`. [Reference Link.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)