# How to return part of string before a certain character?

Tags: javascript, substring

If you look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jEQQg/) from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092325/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-before-a-in-javascript),

```
var str = "Abc: Lorem ipsum sit amet";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

This returns all characters after the `:`, how can I adjust this to return all the characters before the `:`

something like
`var str_sub = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(":")+1);` but this does not work.

Comment: it already returns all the characters after the :

Comment: @Smudger: In your linked fiddle you are using `str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);` which seems to work, the alert does show `Lorem ipsum sit amet`. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry all, I got my before and after messed up... so I am wanting to display the `Abc` not the `Lorem ipsum sit amet`. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for the content after the ":" your code helped me

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You fiddle already does the job ... maybe you try to get the string **before** the double colon? (you really should edit your question) Then the code would go like this:

**`str.substring(0, str.indexOf(":"));`**

Where 'str' represents the variable with your string inside.

[Click here for JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6oqLv6jL/323/)

Javascript

```
var input_string = document.getElementById('my-input').innerText;
var output_element = document.getElementById('my-output');

var left_text = input_string.substring(0, input_string.indexOf(":"));

output_element.innerText = left_text;
```

Html

```
<p>
  <h5>Input:</h5>
  <strong id="my-input">Left Text:Right Text</strong>
  <h5>Output:</h5>
  <strong id="my-output">XXX</strong>
</p>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color:#555; }
h5 { margin-bottom: 0.8em; }
strong {
  width:90%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#my-output { background-color: gold; }
```

Comment: @stonyau I does the job. Could you please explain how you got to this opinion?

Comment: I think you should avoid including a bunch of unrelated css and html in your answers

Comment: @geg If you read the first comment you find out that someone didn't understood how to use the code so I enhanced the answer to be as clear as possible. Stackoverflow rules says that I have to include the code here even if it's an external fiddle. Regardless the first lines give you all you need to know so you can simply ignore the rest.

Comment: @Hexodus your variable naming `right_text` might be confusing as you're really getting the "left text", aren't you...?

Comment: @webeno You're right this was confusing as hell so I updated my answer according to your suggestion. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Answer (score 41):

Another method could be to split the string by ":" and then pop off the end.
 `var newString = string.split(":").pop();`

Comment: Perfect to me, removing the first part.

Comment: This is my favorite solution because if you're identifier is a string of characters this works prefectly. Substr would have to account for the length of the identifier as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the method above, to obtain everything after the colon character in a string.

Answer (score 6):

And note that first argument of subString is 0 based while second is one based.

Example:

```
String str= "0123456";
String sbstr= str.substring(0,5);
```

Output will be `sbstr= 01234` and not `sbstr = 012345`

Answer (score 6):

In General a function to return string after substring is

```js
function getStringAfterSubstring(parentString, substring) {
    return parentString.substring(parentString.indexOf(substring) + substring.length)
}

function getStringBeforeSubstring(parentString, substring) {
    return parentString.substring(0, parentString.indexOf(substring))
}
console.log(getStringAfterSubstring('abcxyz123uvw', '123'))
console.log(getStringBeforeSubstring('abcxyz123uvw', '123'))
```

Answer (score -1):

The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

```
// substring(indexStart, indexEnd); // syntax
// in your case
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(":"));
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470330/2227743).