# Find string and get beside string with simple html dom

Tags: html, string, dom, get

maybe you can help me?
I am trying to do this :

```
Hello the date is xxxx-xx-xx
```

I want to search the string "Hello the date is"
and always take the next 10 characters to the right, so :

```
xxxx-xx-xx
```

i use Curl and Simple html dom

Thanks for answers

Comment: I think, this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470113/how-to-return-part-of-string-after-a-certain-character

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if possible, I would not like to use JS