# Parse content from <title> tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My page looks like this

```
<head>
<title>story : cat</title>
```

Sometimes the title also looks like `story | cat`. This title is getting captured inside an anchor tag.

```
<a class="results" heref="www.hello.com" title="story : cat"/> 
<a class="results" heref="www.hello.com" title="story | cat"/>
```

How can I truncate the title value inside the anchor tag using javascript only to capture just the story-

```
<a class="results" heref="www.hello.com" title="story"/>
```

Comment: _"This title is getting captured inside an anchor tag."_ How?

Comment: So, `<title>` or `<a title="…">`, which do you mean now?

Comment: If your title **always has "story" word as the first word and has a "space" after it**, you may like to split the title by "space", and then return the first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer in this post [How to remove part of a string before a ":" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092325/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-before-a-in-javascript)

You can use one of these methods easily:

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('results')[0].getAttribute("title"); //Use loop for other indexes 
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

OR

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('results')[0].getAttribute("title"); //Use loop for other indexes
str = str.split(":").pop();
```

This solution is more scalable because you don't hardcode the index in which the Colon or the | character is located. You use functions to locate it, so you can later change the keyword and it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

Split on the separator (use a simple regexp to split on *either* `:` or `|`) then pick the first part (and `trim()` it to remove extra spaces), assuming there is only ever two parts, and if there is more, that only the first is of interest:

```
"story : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'story'
"story | cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'story'
"dog : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'dog'
"story : chapter : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'story'
```

Also works on multi-word first parts and with punctuation other than `:` and `|`:

```
"once upon a story : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'once upon a story'
"hey! a story? : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'hey! a story?'
"ß—¯±× : cat".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> 'ß—¯±×'
"物語 : 猫".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> '物語'
```

---

Here's a few examples with potentially problematic inputs, for evaluating the effectiveness of this answer.

If the title is empty or does not contain `:` or `|`:

```
"".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
"foo bar".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() => 'foo bar'
```

If the title contains *only* (any number of) `:`:

```
":".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
":::".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
"|".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
"|||||".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
" : : : ".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
" : | : | : ".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
":|:|:".split(/[:|]/)[0].trim() //=> ''
```

---

Comparing to other answers:

#### substring(0, 5)

```
"story : cat" -> "story"
"story | cat" -> "story"
"dog : cat" -> "dog :"
"story : chapter : cat" -> "story"
"once upon a story : cat" -> "once "
"hey! a story? : cat" -> "hey! "
"ß—¯±× : cat" -> "ß—¯±×"
"物語 : 猫" -> "物語 : "
"" -> ""
"foo bar" -> "foo b"
":" -> ":"
":::" -> ":::"
"|" -> "|"
"|||||" -> "|||||"
" : : : " -> " : : "
" : | : | : " -> " : | "
":|:|:" -> ":|:|:"
```

#### /^\w+/ using `.match()`

```
"story : cat" -> "story"
"story | cat" -> "story"
"dog : cat" -> "dog"
"story : chapter : cat" -> "story"
"once upon a story : cat" -> "once"
"hey! a story? : cat" -> "hey"
"ß—¯±× : cat" -> ""
"物語 : 猫" -> ""
"" -> ""
"foo bar" -> "foo"
":" -> ""
":::" -> ""
"|" -> ""
"|||||" -> ""
" : : : " -> ""
" : | : | : " -> ""
":|:|:" -> ""
```

#### /^\w+/ using `.replace()`

```
"story : cat" -> "story"
"story | cat" -> "story"
"dog : cat" -> "dog"
"story : chapter : cat" -> "story"
"once upon a story : cat" -> "once"
"hey! a story? : cat" -> "hey"
"ß—¯±× : cat" -> "ß—¯±× : cat"
"物語 : 猫" -> "物語 : 猫"
"" -> ""
"foo bar" -> "foo"
":" -> ":"
":::" -> ":::"
"|" -> "|"
"|||||" -> "|||||"
" : : : " -> " : : : "
" : | : | : " -> " : | : | : "
":|:|:" -> ":|:|:"
```

#### substring(.indexOf(':') + 1)

```
"story : cat" -> " cat"
"story | cat" -> "story | cat"
"dog : cat" -> " cat"
"story : chapter : cat" -> " chapter : cat"
"once upon a story : cat" -> " cat"
"hey! a story? : cat" -> " cat"
"ß—¯±× : cat" -> " cat"
"物語 : 猫" -> " 猫"
"" -> ""
"foo bar" -> "foo bar"
":" -> ""
":::" -> "::"
"|" -> "|"
"|||||" -> "|||||"
" : : : " -> " : : "
" : | : | : " -> " | : | : "
":|:|:" -> "|:|:"
```

#### split and .pop()

Functionally equivalent to mine, except without the `.trim()`.

```
"story : cat" -> " cat"
"story | cat" -> " cat"
"dog : cat" -> " cat"
"story : chapter : cat" -> " cat"
"once upon a story : cat" -> " cat"
"hey! a story? : cat" -> " cat"
"ß—¯±× : cat" -> " cat"
"物語 : 猫" -> " 猫"
"" -> ""
"foo bar" -> "foo bar"
":" -> ""
":::" -> ""
"|" -> ""
"|||||" -> ""
" : : : " -> " "
" : | : | : " -> " "
":|:|:" -> ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the substring method.
Pass your title into a var then substring it.

var str = "story : cat";

var res = str.substring(0, 5);

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var results = documet.getElementsByTagName("results")[0].getAttribute("title");
var str = results.substring(0,5);
var str2 = results.slice(0,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title of the page using:

```
document.title;
```

You can get the first word of the title using:

```
var titleFirstWord = document.title.replace(/(^\w+).*/,'$1');
```

I don't know how you want to get a reference to the link, but once you've done that, you can use:

```
linkRef.title = titleFirstWord.
```

Here's an example. Hover over the link to see what the title has been set to.

```js
  
    var titleFirstWord = document.title.replace(/(^\w+).*/,'$1');
    document.links[0].title = titleFirstWord;
```

```html
<head>
  <title>story : cat</title>
</head>
<a href="http://www.foo.com" title="whatever">whatever</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/^\w+/` to match 0 or more word characters at beginning of `document.title` ; also substituting `href` for `heref` at `a` element

```js
document.querySelector(".results")
.setAttribute("title", document.title.match(/^\w+/))
```

```html
<head>
<title>story : cat</title>
  </head>
<a class="results" href="www.hello.com" title="">title</a>
```