# How to cut a string at the end delimited by a special character when this character is used multiple times within the same string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to splice the last part of a string until we reach the first `/` character backwards. Which means if I have the following:

```
str = "Hello/World/Peace";
```

I would only like to take:

```
str = "Hello/World";
```

Where `/Peace` is removed.

The string could be longer: `a/b/c/d/e/f` so the result would always be by removing the last slash with what comes next => `a/b/c/d/e`.

I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092325/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-before-a-in-javascript), but it only works if there is only one slash:

```
str = "hello/world/wide/peace";
new_str = str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1);
```

And the result is by splicing at the beginning not the end of it:

```
new_str = "world/wide/peace";
```

The desired output should be:

```
new_str = "hello/world/wide"
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alim1990/o6wd3mpt/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

Given that `str` is `hello/world/wide/peace`, `str.lastIndexOf("/")` will find the last occurence of `/` in `str`. And then you slice the string from the beginning up to that index, and you take all that and you get `hello/world/wide`

```js
var str = "hello/world/wide/peace";
console.log(str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

The snippet logs `hello/world/wide` to the console.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```js
const removeLastSegment = (input, separator = '/') => {
  const segments = input.split(separator);
 
  segments.pop();
  
  return segments.join(separator);
}

var str = "hello/world/wide/peace";


console.log(removeLastSegment(str));
```