# JavaScript remove a character from a string and remove the previous character

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

How do I remove a character from a string and remove the previous character as well?

Example:

```
"ABCXDEXFGHXIJK"
```

I want to split the string by "X" and remove the previous character which returns

```
"ABDFGIJK" // CX, EX, HX are removed
```

I found this thread but it removes everything before rather than a specific amount of characters: [How to remove part of a string before a ":" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092325/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-before-a-in-javascript)

I can run a for loop but I was wondering if there was a better/simpler way to achieve this

```js
const remove = function(str){
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] === "X") str = str.slice(0, i - 1) + str.slice(i + 1);
  }
  return str
}

console.log(remove("ABCXDEXFGHXIJK")) // ABDFGIJK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` and regex.

```
"ABCXDEXFGHXIJK".replace(/.X/g, '')
```

The `g` at the end is to replace every occurrence of `.X`. You can use `replaceAll` as well, but it has less support.

```
"ABCXDEXFGHXIJK".replaceAll(/.X/g, '')
```

If you want it to be case insensitive, use the `i` flag as well.

```
"ABCXDEXFGHXIJK".replace(/.x/gi, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a regular expression inside `replace`.

```
"ABCXDEXFGHXIJK".replace(/.X/g, "")
```

`.X` means "match the combination of X and any single character before it, `g` flag after the expression body repeats the process globally (instead of doing it once).

Answer (score 0):

While not the most computationally efficient, you *could* use the following one-liner that may meet your definition of "*a better/simpler way to achieve  this*":

```js
const remove = str => str.split("X").map((ele, idx) => idx !== str.split("X").length - 1 ? ele.slice(0, ele.length - 1) : ele).join("");
  

console.log(remove("ABCXDEXFGHXIJK"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use recursion.

```js
function removeChar(str, char){
     
     const index = str.indexOf(char);
     if(index < 0) return str;
     // removes 2 characters from string
     return removeChar(str.split('').splice(index - 2, index).join());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (Descriptive comments are added in the below code snippet itself) **:**

```js
// Input string
const str = "ABCXDEXFGHXIJK";

// split the input string based on 'X' and then remove the last item from each element by using String.slice() method.
const splittedStrArr = str.split('X').map(item => item = item.slice(0, -1));

// Output by joining the modified array elements.
console.log(splittedStr.join(''))
```

By using `RegEx` **:**

```js
// Input string
const str = "ABCXDEXFGHXIJK";

// Replace the input string by matching the 'X' and one character before that with an empty string.
const modifiedStr = str.replace(/.X/g, "")

// Output
console.log(modifiedStr)
```